# How to avoid row splitting for jasper-report excel export

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I'm trying to create Jasper Report with 2 tables in Detail band and export it into 3 formats (PDF, DOCX and XLS), and there is an issue with 2nd table when exporting to XLS:

The table's row may take the height of 2 pages (last column field's content can be really large). So for DOCX and PDF formats it is totally okay that the export result has 2 pages containing similar row with the only difference in the last column value - first and second part of the column value after splitting. I am using pagination for this formats.

In XLS file such behavior is confusing - first column value is logically unique, but because of splitting it contains 2 lines in a row with the same 'unique' value. I set this property to avoid pagination for this format:

`<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.paginated" value="false"/>`

The result looks like this:
[duplicate for split row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf39W.png)

I would like to join this to rows values. Maybe there is a way to merge such rows specially in XLS format. Please, help to find a workaround.

My report level properties are:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1" value="pageHeader"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.2" value="columnHeader"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.key.padding"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.key.pages"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.collapse.row.span" value="false"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.collapse.column.span" value="false"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background" value="false"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.cell.border" value="false"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.font.size.fix.enabled" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.consume.space.on.overflow" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.paginated" value="false"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.docx.frames.as.tables" value="false"/>
```

Properties for the last column text field:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="true"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Set Detail band property "Split Type" to "Prevent"

https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/set-detail-band-property-split-type-prevent

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).